# Fibonacci Sequence - Time Complexity

Tags: time-complexity

Given that fib(n)=fib(n-1)+fib(n-2) for n>1 and given that fib(0)=a, fib(1)=b (some a, b >0), which of the following is true?

```
fib(n) is 

Select one or more:
a. O(n^2)
b. O(2^n)
c. O((1-sqrt 5)/2)^n)
d. O(n)
e. Answer depends on a and b.
f. O((1+sqrt 5)/2)^n)
```

Solving the Fibonacci sequence I got that:

```
fib(n)= 1/(sqrt 5) ((1+sqrt 5)/2)^n - 1/(sqrt 5) ((1-sqrt 5)/2)^n
```

But what would be the time complexity in this case? Would that mean the answers are c and f?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your closed form of your formula, the term `1 / (sqrt 5) ((1 - sqrt 5) / 2)^n` has limit `0` as `n` grows to infinity (`|(1 - sqrt 5) / 2| < 1`). Therefore we can ignore this term. Also since in time complexity theory we don't care about muliplication constants the following is true:

> fib(n) = Θ(φ^n)

where φ = `(1 + sqrt 5) / 2` a.k.a. the [golden ratio constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio).

So it's an exponential function and we can exclude `a, d, e`. We can exclude `c` since as was said it has limit `0`. But answer `b` is also correct because `φ < 2` and `O` expresses an upper bound.

Finally, the correct answers are:

> b, f

Answer (score 1):

Θ(φ^n) is correct when `a=1 and b=1` or `a=1 and b=2` . `The value of φ depends on a and b`.

For computing fib(n-1) and fib(n-2) if we compute them recursively complexity is `exponential`, but if we save two last values and use them, complexity is `O(n)` and not depends on a and b.